# GIS data for disease vectors

Tags: data, vector, health

Does anyone know where to find disease information in ESRI Shape vector format? I am trying to track zika, dengue, and flu in local communities, but any others are welcome too. My attempts so far are listed below

- most of the "GIS" links on the CDC's website are broken
- the WHO data is almost entirely pdf
- NIH data is pdf and very broad, state/country wide generalizations
- USGS social data is "retired"

Comment: Could you probably be a litte more specific, what you mean by 'desease information', since I do not know exacly what ist meant here. First occurence of a certain desease, where and when or s.l.t.?

Comment: we have a gis server that we sell access to for tracking assets in the field (things like cargo containers and heavy equipment) and one of our customers asked us for a layer that would show them any infection disease risks in the areas they plan to send workers into. What are the risks for going into the Congo to drill an oil well, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The NBIC DHS may have some data.

May find something here
http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/

Answer (score 0):

ESRI has their open data on their online and what's nice about it is that you can preview the data and their attribute table before you can download it.

http://opendata.arcgis.com/